# AOP: Domain model to Axis beans and vice versa

Tags: java, aop, apache-axis, aspectj, spring-aop

This is a design question for those who are hopefully a bit more familiar with Spring/AOP than myself.

I have a set of domain model beans populated from various web forms. I have a requirement to submit the domain model contents to a number of web services and I will be using Axis2 to do so.

Somewhere in my code I will have to tackle the laborious task of collating the information required from my domain objects and putting it into the Axis2 beans. For the most part this is as simple as:

```
AxisObject.setTheString(DomainObject.getTheString())
```

Ideally, I would like to keep Axis related code away from my domain objects, but a tidy solution for me is to have a method on the domain object e.g. putContentsInAxisBean()

My question is this: could I use features of AOP (e.g. introductions) to add this kind of functionality to my domain objects when required? Or otherwise, is there some other design pattern emerging here?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It's nothing to do with the AOP. You should look for a bean mapper, e.g. there is a [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/), but I've not tried it myself. However, I would prefer explicit mapping code like you quoted, it makes the code navigation and refactoring easier.